# Zabbix Docker Ansible

Tags: ansible, zabbix

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки!

Есть система: сервер и ~200 хостов присоединённых к ней. Есть задача всё это дело контролировать. В целом всё получается, устанавливаются Zabbix Agent`ы и различные метрики приходят на сервер, все счастливы.

Данная схема реализована через Docker контейнеры на стороне сервера.

Всё хорошо, но иногда надо внести какая-то коррективы, написать новый UserParameter, либо временно отключить агентов на определенных хостатх.
Делать всё это вручную работа ставни аЦкой.

Я скачала Docker Image Ansible (для меня было откровением его размер: ~ 2Gb)

Не подскажите примеров или как кам можно использовать Ansible для автоматизации уже имеющейся рабочей схеме?

Как совместить одно с другом?

Огромное сипастибо!

Comment: Ну это слишком объёмный вопрос, поэтому почитайте вводную в [примерах](https://habr.com/ru/post/305400/) что-бы понять идеологию.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Но у меня специфичная ситуация: у меня уже развернута система Zabbix на базе Docker. И теперь бы мне хотелось использовать Ansible для механизации рутинных работ: изменить или добавить UserParameter, заменить скрипты на хостах разом, а не заходя на каждый по отдельности (~ 200 unit)
Ну и главное чтобы это всё работало под управлением Docker
Каких-либо внятных примеров я не нашел, только общие слова.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы можете зайти в контейнер по SSH, значит Ansible у вас будет работать с этими контейнерами.

Comment: я не увидел как можно запулить Ansible контейнер, чтобы потом с ним работать 

условлно: **Docker run -it -d --name my_ansible Ansible/ansible**

Comment: @Oxyd, почти. Нужны ещё пакеты python. `python-minimal` вроде бы достаточно для базовых штук.

Comment: А, ну да... У zabbix-а python-а в зависимостях нема, так что придётся ставить.

Comment: @speedy-gonzales Эхх... Пришлось на этот куркулятор, который у меня сейчас вместо основного ноута, который на ремонте, докер городить... Вобщем на докерхабе образов с ансиблом, как у дурака фантиков... И они [даже работают](https://i.imgur.com/30OPrW5.png). Единственное что, вам потребуется, наличие минимального python-а и SSH, на хостах с докером.

Comment: Вопрос дурацкий но зачем вам докер под забикс? У каждого дистра есть пакет. Он взлетает с 0выми конфигами размер пакета вы не поверите - >меньшье 10мб. с асамблем так же пакет есть в любом дистрибутиве. Из pip можно свеженькую загрузить. Перечислите все хосты в инвинтаре расскидайте ключи и здравствуйте без докера (если реч о железе) у меня было 5000 точек под ансамблем напрямую.

Comment: У вас СЕТЬ с хостами или СЕРВЕР с виртуалками? В вопросе не понял.

Comment: Отключать агентов на стороне хомта нет смысла - у сервера есть параметр "отлючить" есть "мейтаненс" где можно отключать сбор. Фишка забикса - создавать структурированные группы.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, уже есть готовые решения для развертывания и поддержки Zabbix server, Zabbix proxy и Zabbix agent. Ссылки [прямо с сайта заббикса](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/ansible).Вот например про рецепт для [Zabbix agent](https://github.com/dj-wasabi/ansible-zabbix-agent).

> This is a role for installing and maintaining the zabbix-agent. It will install the Zabbix Agent on any host with an operating system that is defined here or will install a Docker container and start that.

Comment: как я понимаю это решения платные 
Я не такой большой знаток Zabbix, хотелось бы наглядных живых примеров, и таких как я достаточное количество.

Comment: Нет, это бесплатные, опенсорсные решения, как и сам ансибл.

Answer (score 0):

используйте плейбук, также создать роль под каждую задачу и в дальнейшем модернизировать и быть счастливым

https://ealebed.github.io/posts/2015/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-ansible-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/

https://ealebed.github.io/posts/2015/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-ansible-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-playbook/

https://ealebed.github.io/posts/2015/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-ansible-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B/

Comment: Ответы содержащие только ссылки, ответами не считаются и обычно удаляются. Было бы неплохо, дополнить ответ основным содержанием по ссылкам.